# Binding - controls are not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have binded controls to some property of type of class that is "describing" progress.

Everything seems to be ok:

- NotifyPropertyChanged seems to work: it raises when properties are changed (in case of updating properties of instance of ProgressViewModel class)
- when looking on xaml code, while code is running, under binded properties proper values are shown (so, for example: Progress is equal to 0.1).

The problem is that visually nothing changes. So: controls are not updated. All.

XAML:

```
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
            <StackPanel x:Name="ProgressPart"
                        DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                        Visibility="{Binding Visible, Converter={StaticResource ValueConverterBoolToVisibility}}">
                <ProgressBar  Value="{Binding Path=Progress, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ValueConverterTest}}" />
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock>
                    <Run Text="Action:" />
                    <Run Text="{Binding Path=ActionName, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ActionProgress, Mode=OneWay }" />

            </StackPanel>


            <StackPanel x:Name="MasterOKPart"
                        DockPanel.Dock="Top">

            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel x:Name="MasterNotOKPart"
                        DockPanel.Dock="Top">

            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel x:Name="FooterPart"
                        DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            </StackPanel>
        </DockPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

control code behind:

```
public partial class ContentAnomalies : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged, IViewControl
{
    private ProgressViewModel _ProgressViewModel;
    public ProgressViewModel ProgressViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return _ProgressViewModel;
        }
        set
        {
            _ProgressViewModel = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _Prepared;
    public bool Prepared
    {
        get
        {
            return _Prepared;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == false)
            {
                _Prepared = value;
                return;
            }
            if (_Prepared==false)
            {
                ProgressViewModel = new ProgressViewModel
                {
                    Visible = true,
                    Token = new CancellationTokenSource()
                };
                Thread myNewThread = new Thread(() => Auditor.AuditContentMD(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation, this, ProgressViewModel));
                myNewThread.Start();
                //ProgressViewModel.Visible = false;

            }
        }
    }

    public ContentAnomalies()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //ProgressViewModel = new ProgressViewModel();
        //ProgressViewModel.Visible = true;
        this.ProgressPart.DataContext = ProgressViewModel;

    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public void Prepare()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

method that is modyfying progressViewModel:

internal static void AuditContentMD(PPT.Presentation pres, ContentAnomalies control, ProgressViewModel progressViewModel)
    {
        List contentAudits = ReturnContentAudits();

```
    progressViewModel.Visible = true;
    progressViewModel.Progress = 0;
    progressViewModel.ActionName = "Loading presentation objects...";
    List<Anomaly> anomalies = new List<Anomaly>();
    Audit audit;

    AuditsSupport.SpacesPositions = null;
    DateTime timeStart = DateTime.Now;
    AuditsSupport.Shapes = SupportVSTO.ReturnAllShapesFromPresentation(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation, progressViewModel, 0, (double)1 / (contentAudits.Count + 1));
    TimeSpan timeShapes = DateTime.Now - timeStart;

    for (int i = 0; i < contentAudits.Count; i++)
    {
        DateTime timeStartInternal = DateTime.Now;

        if (progressViewModel.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            audit = contentAudits[i];
            progressViewModel.ActionName = audit.Name;
            anomalies.AddRange(contentAudits[i].PerformAudit(pres, (double)(i + 1) / (contentAudits.Count + 1), (double)1 / (contentAudits.Count + 1), progressViewModel));
        }
        progressViewModel.Progress = (double)(i + 2) / (contentAudits.Count + 1);
    }
    TimeSpan timeWhole = DateTime.Now - timeStart;
    MessageBox.Show("all:" + "    " + timeWhole.TotalSeconds);

    //control.ShowProgressBar(false);
    //control.AddAuditsListControlToPanel(anomalies, pres);
}
```

And PogressViewModelClass:

```
public class ProgressViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double _Progress;
    public double Progress
    {
        get
        {
            return _Progress;
        }
        set
        {
            _Progress = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private string _ActionName;
    public string ActionName
    {
        get
        {
            return _ActionName;
        }
        set
        {
            _ActionName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string _ActionProgress;
    public string ActionProgress
    {
        get
        {
            return _ActionProgress;
        }
        set
        {
            _ActionProgress = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _Visible;
    public bool Visible
    {
        get
        {
            return _Visible;
        }
        set
        {
            _Visible = true;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private CancellationTokenSource _Token;
    public CancellationTokenSource Token
    {
        get
        {
            return _Token;
        }
        set
        {
            _Token = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public ProgressViewModel()
    {

    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: All controls are not updated.

Comment: Where are you setting your `DataContext`?

Comment: If i see it right, you call the Method that changes your Properties in a different Thread, have you tried invoking the Changes in the Dispatcher?

Comment: When you set `this.ProgressPart.DataContext = ProgressViewModel`, the ProgressViewModel property has to be initialized before. If you assign a value later, the DataContext isn't magically updated, and just stays null. You may however bind the DataContext property to the ProgressViewModel property.

Comment: Decoder94:  In a ContentAnomalies constructtor

Comment: Spongebrot: from what I read there is no need to use dispatcher in case of using binding

Comment: Clemens: Thank you very much! Initializing ProgressViewModel before assigning it to DataContext helped.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried adding the PropertyName to NotifyPropertyChanged?
like 'NotifyPropertyChanged("ActionName")'

propably its in your binding, it should be like this:

TextBlock Text="{Binding ActionProgress, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"

there is no need for Mode=OneWay as its the default setting

Comment: I will try it later.

Comment: if it works please mark my answer as correct, i have received alot of help on so and want to upvote those that helped me, thanks :)

Comment: Setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` only makes sense on a TwoWay or OneWayToSource Binding. It is pointless here. It is often misunderstood, but is has nothing to do with the PropertyChanged event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: And passing the property name in the NotifyPropertyChanged call is redundant, since the method argument has the CallerMemberName attribute set.

Comment: @Clemens for someone who is new to the whole thing there might be a lot of information to get started. since what you wrote was informative i just thanked, but your last comment is pretty useless, right?

Comment: That's wrong. Both of your suggestions don't make sense. They are redundant and hence useless. In fact they only create additional confusion. Unless you haven't understood what it *really* does, you should never set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`.